# Batch file to pull a random string from a file and loop a random number of times

Tags: windows, random, for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will loop a random number of times between 2 and 10 and pull a random line from a text file each time and display it.

```
set var1=%RANDOM%
set /a var2=(var1*9/32768)+2
for /l %%x in (1,1,%var2%) do (
set "lines=0" 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\myfile.txt) do set /a "lines+=1" 
set /a "skip=%var1% %% lines" 
if %skip% lss 1 (set "skip=") else (set "skip=skip=%skip%")
for /f "skip=%skip% tokens=*" %%a in (c:\myfile.txt) do set "item=%%a"&goto display

:display
echo %item%
)
```

This is two different pieces of code that each work on their own, but I am having trouble putting them together.

The code below will display a random line from the file every time I run it.

```
set "lines=0" 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\myfile.txt) do set /a "lines+=1" 
set /a "skip=%random% %% lines" 
if %skip% lss 1 (set "skip=") else (set "skip=skip=%skip%") 
for /f "%skip% tokens=*" %%a in (c:\myfile.txt) do set "item=%%a"&goto display 
:display 
echo %item%
```

And this code will display 1 between 2 and 10 times.

```
@echo off
set var1=%RANDOM%
set /a var2=(var1*9/32768)+2
for /l %%x in (1,1,%var2%) do (
echo 1
)
```

I'm probably just overlooking the obvious, but I don't do a lot of batch scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems:

- You define variable `skip` within a parenthesized block (the DO clause) and then attempt to use `%skip%` within the same loop. That can't work because the variable is expanded when the entire code block is parsed - before the value is set! Normally the solution is to use delayed expansion, but you can't used delayed expansion within FOR /F options. The solution is to CALL outside of the block.
- Your logic uses the same random number for each iteration. I interpret your stated requirement to mean you want to use a different random number for each iteration.
- Your GOTO breaks your FOR loop. The loop will not proceed to the next iteration if you issue a GOTO.
- Your computation for `var2` is not good. It can fail if `%RANDOM%*9` exceeds the maximum value for a 4 byte signed int. I also don't think it is giving the distribution of values that you want. You should use the mod operator like you do for the random line number.
- The value for the SKIP option must be >= 1. If you want 0 then you must omit the option entirely. Your isolated code does this properly, but your broken code is, ummmm broken :-)

Additional improvements:

- You compute the number of lines in the file each iteration. You only need to do that once.
- It is much more efficient to use FIND to count the number of lines and capture the value using FOR /F. FOR /F ignores blank lines, so I use FINDSTR to find all non empty lines, and pipe those results to FIND to get the count.
- Using `TOKENS=*` will strip leading spaces, whereas `DELIMS=` will preserve the whole line.
- The default EOL option is `EOL=;`, which means any line that begins with `;` will be ignored. The weird syntax with carets before each space and equal and the absence of quotes  is needed to set EOL to nothing.
- I added quotes around the file name and added the USEBACKQ option in case your file name includes spaces.

Here is a working solution

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=c:\myfile.txt"
for /f %%N in ('findstr "." "%file%"^|find /c /v ""') do set lines=%%N
set /a "iterations=%random% %% 8 + 2"
for /l %%N in (1 1 %iterations%) do call :printRandomLine
exit /b

:printRandomLine
set /a "skip=%random% %% %lines%"
if %skip% lss 1 (set "skip=") else set "skip=skip^=%skip%"
for /f usebackq^ %skip%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%file%") do (
  echo %%A
  exit /b
)
```